# WP - shortcode including a mixture of html and php (ACF variables)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I'm trying to create a WP shortcode that would include both html and php. For example, something like that (that does not work):

```
function my_first_shortcode() {
    $content = <<<EOT
    <h1>Some title</h1>
    <p><?php the_field('description'); ?></p>
EOT;
return $content; 
} 
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_first_shortcode');
```

The the_field('name_of_field'); normally outputs the content of the specified variable/field (Advanced Custom Fields).

Is the HEREDOC way the right way of doing that? If so, how would I do it? It'd be also great if I could pass variables to the shortcode.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always prefer to use output buffering for my shortcodes, example below.

```
function my_first_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); ?>
    <h1>Some title</h1>
    <p><?php echo the_field('description'); ?></p>
    <?php
    return ob_get_contents();
} 
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_first_shortcode');
```

Comment: hmm. It does the job but it outputs it in 2 places on a page: at the bottom (after the main content (and this is where I placed the shortcode), and at the top right after the title.

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with the small function above, there must be another reason why it is outputtimg twice

Comment: I think it might have. After some googling, I've changed ob_get_contents to ob_get_clean and it fixed it. I don't really understand what it did but it worked

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't write PHP tags inside HEREDOC.
You can use it like that:

```
$the_field = 'the_field';
$content = <<<EOT
<h1>Some title</h1>
<p>{$the_field('description')}</p>
EOT;
```

In order to pass attributes to a shortcode it's very simple.
for example we have the shortcode:

> [my_shortcode att_1="some_value" att_2="some_value"]

```
function my_first_shortcode($atts)
{
    $att_1 = $atts['att_1'];
    $att_2 = $atts['att_2'];
}
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_first_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_shortcode('location_start_your_application_group', 'start_your_application_group');

function start_your_application_group() {
    ob_start();

    $start_your_application_group = '';
    $start_your_application_group .= '<section class="start-your-application">';
     if ( have_rows( 'start_your_application_group', 'option' ) ) : 
         while ( have_rows( 'start_your_application_group', 'option' ) ) : the_row(); 
           $heading = get_sub_field( 'heading' );
             $content = get_sub_field( 'content' );

             if ( $heading !== '' ) {
                    $start_your_application_group .= '<h3 class="start-your-application__heading">' . $heading . '</h3>';
             }
             if ( $content !== '' ) {
                $start_your_application_group .= '<div class="start-your-application__content">' . $content . '</div>';
             }

             $image = get_sub_field( 'image' );
             if ( $image ) { 
                $start_your_application_group .= '<div class="start-your-application__image-container"><img class="start-your-application__image" src="' . esc_url($image['url']) .'" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" /></div>';
            } 
        endwhile;
    endif;

    $start_your_application_group .= '</section>';
    $start_your_application_group = ob_get_clean();

    return $start_your_application_group;
}
```